# If / else statement seems lengthy, looking for ways to simplify code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking at my code, the section containing the if/else statement works exactly how I want it to in `scripts.js`, but it doesn't feel like the most efficient approach to the problem.

## Problem

I have a small navigation *(on the left)* that shows seven pet names. The total list of pets up for adoption is forty. As the user scrolls down the page, the HTML and the link, in the navigation, containing the pet names changes after every seven pets.

## JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8cnq58x4/1/

`(You may have to expand the "Result" window to see the small navigation)`

## scripts.js

```
$(function(){
      /*-------------------------------------
      TABLETOP.JS
      --------------------------------------*/
      var public_spreadsheet_url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TOIGfwdi1GhV7BMhc5fH481icHi7zEEyXZZx3Y5J61I/pubhtml";

      $(document).ready( function() {
        Tabletop.init( { key: public_spreadsheet_url,
            callback: showInfo,
            parseNumbers: true } );
      });
      function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
        var source   = $("#pets").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

        // The actual name of the sheet, not entire .csv
        $.each(tabletop.sheets("Pets").all(), function(i, fact) {
            var html = template(fact);

          // You need an element with this id or class in your HTML
          $("#pets-list").append(html);
          $('.container').eq(i).addClass(data.Pets.elements[i]);
          // console.log(data.Pets.elements[i].name);

            // Deals with the left menu
            $(".nameNav").click(function(){
               $(".nameNav").removeClass("active");
               $(this).toggleClass("active");
            });

            /* -------------------------------------
            NAVIGATION
            --------------------------------------*/

            $(window).scroll(function(){
                var $pets = $('.pet').map(function(_, i){
                    return $(i).offset().top;
                });

                var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                  var index = $pets.filter(function(i, v){ if(v < scroll) return i; }).length;
                  $(".nameNav").removeClass("active");
                  $(".nameNav").eq(index).addClass("active");

                  var navElements = $(".nameNav"); navElements.eq(index % navElements.length).addClass("active");

                  if (index >= 7 && index <= 13) {
                     $(".first").html(data.Pets.elements[7].name);
                     $("#pet-one").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[7].name);

                     $(".second").html(data.Pets.elements[8].name);
                     $("#pet-two").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[8].name);

                     $(".third").html(data.Pets.elements[9].name);
                     $("#pet-three").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[9].name);

                     $(".fourth").html(data.Pets.elements[10].name);
                     $("#pet-four").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[10].name);

                     $(".fifth").html(data.Pets.elements[11].name);
                     $("#pet-five").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[11].name);

                     $(".sixth").html(data.Pets.elements[12].name);
                     $("#pet-six").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[12].name);

                     $(".seventh").html(data.Pets.elements[13].name);
                     $("#pet-seven").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[13].name);

                  } else if (index >= 14 && index <= 20) {
                     $(".first").html(data.Pets.elements[14].name);
                     $("#pet-one").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[14].name);

                     $(".second").html(data.Pets.elements[15].name);
                     $("#pet-two").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[15].name);

                     $(".third").html(data.Pets.elements[16].name);
                     $("#pet-three").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[16].name);

                     $(".fourth").html(data.Pets.elements[17].name);
                     $("#pet-four").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[17].name);

                     $(".fifth").html(data.Pets.elements[18].name);
                     $("#pet-five").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[18].name);

                     $(".sixth").html(data.Pets.elements[19].name);
                     $("#pet-six").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[19].name);

                     $(".seventh").html(data.Pets.elements[20].name);
                     $("#pet-seven").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[20].name);

                  } else if (index >= 21 && index <= 27) {
                    $(".first").html(data.Pets.elements[21].name);
                    $("#pet-one").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[21].name);

                    $(".second").html(data.Pets.elements[22].name);
                    $("#pet-two").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[22].name);

                    $(".third").html(data.Pets.elements[23].name);
                    $("#pet-three").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[23].name);

                    $(".fourth").html(data.Pets.elements[24].name);
                    $("#pet-four").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[24].name);

                    $(".fifth").html(data.Pets.elements[25].name);
                    $("#pet-five").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[25].name);

                    $(".sixth").html(data.Pets.elements[26].name);
                    $("#pet-six").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[26].name);

                    $(".seventh").html(data.Pets.elements[27].name);
                    $("#pet-seven").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[27].name);

                  } else if (index >= 28 && index <= 34) {
                    $(".first").html(data.Pets.elements[28].name);
                    $("#pet-one").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[28].name);

                    $(".second").html(data.Pets.elements[29].name);
                    $("#pet-two").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[29].name);

                    $(".third").html(data.Pets.elements[30].name);
                    $("#pet-three").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[30].name);

                    $(".fourth").html(data.Pets.elements[31].name);
                    $("#pet-four").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[31].name);

                    $(".fifth").html(data.Pets.elements[32].name);
                    $("#pet-five").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[32].name);

                    $(".sixth").html(data.Pets.elements[33].name);
                    $("#pet-six").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[33].name);

                    $(".seventh").html(data.Pets.elements[34].name);
                    $("#pet-seven").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[34].name);

                  } else if (index >= 35 && index <= 38) {
                    $(".first").html(data.Pets.elements[35].name);
                    $("#pet-one").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[35].name);

                    $(".second").html(data.Pets.elements[36].name);
                    $("#pet-two").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[36].name);

                    $(".third").html(data.Pets.elements[37].name);
                    $("#pet-three").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[37].name);

                    $(".fourth").html(data.Pets.elements[38].name);
                    $("#pet-four").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[38].name);
                  } else {
                    $(".first").html(data.Pets.elements[0].name);
                    $("#pet-one").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[0].name);

                    $(".second").html(data.Pets.elements[1].name);
                    $("#pet-two").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[1].name);

                    $(".third").html(data.Pets.elements[2].name);
                    $("#pet-three").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[2].name);

                    $(".fourth").html(data.Pets.elements[3].name);
                    $("#pet-four").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[3].name);

                    $(".fifth").html(data.Pets.elements[4].name);
                    $("#pet-five").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[4].name);

                    $(".sixth").html(data.Pets.elements[5].name);
                    $("#pet-six").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[5].name);

                    $(".seventh").html(data.Pets.elements[6].name);
                    $("#pet-seven").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[6].name);
                  }

                  /* -------------------------------------
                  HIDE SOME PETS
                  --------------------------------------*/

                  if (index >= 35 && index <= 38) {
                    $(".fifth").addClass("hide");
                    $(".sixth").addClass("hide");
                    $(".seventh").addClass("hide");
                  } else {
                    $(".fifth").removeClass("hide");
                    $(".sixth").removeClass("hide");
                    $(".seventh").removeClass("hide");
                  }
      });
    });
    };
});
```

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Name of Website</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/favicon.ico"> -->
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="vertical">
        <div class="rectangle">
            <a href="#Adonis" id="pet-one"><p class="nameNav first active">Adonis</p></a>
            <a href="#Billy" id="pet-two"><p class="nameNav second">Billy</p></a>
            <a href="#Comet" id="pet-three"><p class="nameNav third">Comet</p></a>
            <a href="#Dexter" id="pet-four"><p class="nameNav fourth">Dexter</p></a>
            <a href="#Evan" id="pet-five"><p class="nameNav fifth">Evan</p></a>
            <a href="#Fritz" id="pet-six"><p class="nameNav sixth">Fritz</p></a>
            <a href="#Grommit" id="pet-seven"><p class="nameNav seventh">Grommit</p></a>
        </div><!-- /.rectangle -->
    </nav>

    <main>
        <div id="pets-list"></div>
    </main>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabletop.js/1.3.5/tabletop.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.js"></script>

        <!-- This is where the template for pets goes -->
        <script id="pets" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="pet">
                    <p class="nameTitle" id="{{name}}">{{name}}</p>
                    <img src="{{image}}" alt="">
                    <p class="breed">{{breed}}</p>
                    <p class="description">{{description}}</p>
                    <p class="cost">{{cost}}</p>
                    <hr>
                </div><!-- /.pet -->
            </div><!-- /.container -->
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For code simplification please see [codereview.stackexchange.com](//codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I do love that site - gotta go in with an open mind that your code is crap - there are some artists over there

Answer (score 5):

Replace the entire if/else block with this:

```
var places_arr = [".first", ".second", ".third", ".fourth", ".fifth", ".sixth", ".seventh"];
var nbs_arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven"];
for(var pet_ind = 0; pet_ind < 7; pet_ind++){
    var final_pet_index = index-(index%7)+pet_ind;
    $(places_arr[pet_ind]).html(data.Pets.elemets[final_pet_index].name);
    $("#pet-"+nbs_arr[pet_ind]).attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[final_pet_index].name);                  
}
```

Comment: I'd pull out the `index-(index%7)+ped_int` just because you compute it twice and you could then give it a name that kinda sorta tells you wtf it's doing, but otherwise best answer

Comment: I really do not understand the reason of so many votes when the above code fails in 2 scenarios - when index is greater than 38 and for scenario in which index lies between 35 and 38 (both inclusive)

Comment: I second @nikhil. Your solution doesnt cover the cases where `35<= index<= 38`. The loop runs 7 times while it should break after the 4th iteration. Also, `mod` is an expensive operation to be performed in loop, specially if the value is not changing. Better keep `index-(index%7)` outside the loop.

Comment: I didn't add the part for 35 <= index <= 38 because his/her "HIDE SOME PETS" section works fine and isn't as long as the other if/else. My code should replace the big if/else block, and not the extra conditions below.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of if else if by following approach

```
// Handling of else scenario
var counter = 0;
if(index > 0 && index <= 38) {
    counter = Math.floor(index/7)*7;
}

// elements classes array 
var arr1 = [".first", ".second", ".third", ".fourth", ".fifth", ".sixth", ".seventh"];
var arr2 = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven"];

// Iteration
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    $(arr1[i]).html(data.Pets.elements[counter+i].name);
    $("#pet-" + arr2[i]).attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[counter+i].name);

    // Handle specific scenario for index 35 to 38.
    if(counter == 35 && i == 3) {
         break;
    }
}

// Additional check for specific scenario for index 35 to 38
if (counter == 35) {
        $(".fifth").addClass("hide");
        $(".sixth").addClass("hide");
        $(".seventh").addClass("hide");
} else {
        $(".fifth").removeClass("hide");
        $(".sixth").removeClass("hide");
        $(".seventh").removeClass("hide");
}
```

Comment: I think that Math.floor(index/7)*7 will not do what you spect when asnwering this question...

Comment: @MatiasCaamaño - You are right. I thought there are blocks of 7, however, after down vote I realized there are some exceptions as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use like a comodin.

You are using a secuence of numbers:

1) From 7 to 13 
2) From 14 to 20
3) From 21 to 27

and so on...

so, for example, yo can see if the index is between some of the limits, and do something like this...

```
if (index >= 7 && index <= 13) {
   comodin=7;
}
if (index >= 14 && index <= 20) {
   comodin=14;
}
...
```

And finnaly:

```
(".first").html(data.Pets.elements[comodin].name);
$("#pet-one").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[comodin].name);

$(".second").html(data.Pets.elements[comodin+1].name);
$("#pet-two").attr("href", "#" + data.Pets.elements[comodin +1].name);
```

... And so on...